# JSON deserialization using GSON skips data members from a hashmap within a hashmap

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson, deserialization

I'm using GSON to deserialize some JSON files.  Here's the deserialization method I've written, I read the JSON file and store the whole thing as a string which I pass to this method.  This method works successfully for 4 out of the 5 JSON files related to this project.

```
protected ArrayList<Entry> deserialize(String json) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<Entry>( );


    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    JsonArray jarray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.size(); i++)
    {

        // Parse out the brand
        JsonObject jentry = (JsonObject) jarray.get(i);

        JsonPrimitive jbrand = jentry.getAsJsonPrimitive("brand");

        String className = jbrand.getAsString();

        Entry entry = (Entry) gson.fromJson(jentry, Class.forName(className));

        list.add(entry);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Here's the JSON file that I parsed and put in the string, there's several objects that get bound to 'jentry' but I'll just include one.  If it looks weird it's probably because I've been using a firefox plugin to view the JSON files and I copy/pasted from that plugin.

```
[

*
  -
  {
      o pattern: "3 5 * * 1-5"
      o starts: 1288249260913
      o ends: 1291125660913
      o skipHolidays: false
      o lastFired: 1289988180395
      o
        -
        template: {
            + location: ""
            + damageCause: ""
            + signed: false
            + signedBy: ""
            + approvedBy: "Ralph"
            + requestedBy: "Ralph"
            + estHours: 0
            + actHours: 0
            + chargeTo: ""
            + priority: "ROUTINE"
            + reason: ""
            + materials: ""
            + serviceId: 1
            + descr: "HELP WITH LEAVES,BLOW LEAVES IN YOUR AREA NEAR DRAINS Check for garbage. [sp] Mow and weedeat where needed in your area. [sp] Work on leaves where needed. [wi]"
            + comments: [ ]
            + futureId: 3
            + inventoryId: -1
            +
              -
              trail: [
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288026816857
                        * status: "OPEN"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288026889374
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288194095170
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288287964481
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288785076532
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288797119525
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289307416921
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289308339165
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289834523635
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289847660913
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
              ]
            + requestDate: 1289329260913
            + assignedDate: 1288029660912
            + supplies: [ ]
            + id: 3
            + updateDate: 1289847660913
            + createUserId: 2
            + updateUserId: 2
            + createDate: 1288026816857
            + brand: "org.workplicity.marist.grounds.GroundsRequest"
        }
      o workSlateId: 16
      o serviceId: 1
      o enabled: false
      o id: 3
      o updateDate: 1291235385719
      o createUserId: 2
      o updateUserId: 2
      o createDate: 1288026889373
      o brand: "org.workplicity.entry.event.Weekdays"
  }
```

The problem is that when the GSON gets turned back into JSON (serialization?) it's missing some fields.  Here's the output, the relevant missing lines are everything below 'template:' and above 'serviceID:', I'll go ahead and include the whole object again.

```
[

*
  -
  {
      o pattern: "3 5 * * 1-5"
      o starts: 1288249260913
      o ends: 1291125660913
      o skipHolidays: false
      o lastFired: 1289988180395
      o
        -
        template: {
            + serviceId: 1
            + descr: "HELP WITH LEAVES,BLOW LEAVES IN YOUR AREA NEAR DRAINS Check for garbage. [sp] Mow and weedeat where needed in your area. [sp] Work on leaves where needed. [wi]"
            + comments: [ ]
            + futureId: 3
            + inventoryId: -1
            +
              -
              trail: [
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288026816857
                        * status: "OPEN"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288026889374
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288194095170
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288287964481
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288785076532
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1288797119525
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289307416921
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289308339165
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289834523635
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
                  #
                    -
                    {
                        * stamp: 1289847660913
                        * status: "DISPATCHED"
                        * byId: 2
                    }
              ]
            + requestDate: 1289329260913
            + assignedDate: 1288029660912
            + supplies: [ ]
            + id: 3
            + updateDate: 1289847660913
            + createUserId: 2
            + updateUserId: 2
            + createDate: 1288026816857
            + brand: "org.workplicity.marist.grounds.GroundsRequest"
        }
      o workSlateId: 16
      o serviceId: 1
      o enabled: false
      o id: 3
      o updateDate: 1299694066807
      o createUserId: 2
      o updateUserId: 2
      o createDate: 1288026889373
      o brand: "org.workplicity.entry.event.Weekdays"
  }
```

This happens for every object in the JSON file.  Debugging in NetBeans has revealed that the JsonObject 'jentry' has a hashtable with corresponding key value pairs for each data member in the JSON string; and the 'template' is stored as a hashtable within this hashtable which may or may not be a problem I honestly haven't been able to find out.

Now when I initially ran this method on the problem JSON file I got an exception at this line:

```
Entry entry = (Entry) gson.fromJson(jentry, Class.forName(className));
```

The problem was that the particular classes involved with this specific JSON file didn't have no-args constructors so I had to register some InstanceCreators to the GSON builder like so:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Weekdays.class, new WeekdaysInstanceCreator());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Once.class, new OnceInstanceCreator());
```

After I did that the exception stopped being thrown and everything appears to have worked, minus the missing fields of course.

So that's where I am, I'm really at a loss as to what's going wrong.  Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When Gson drops a field present in JSON it is usually because the class that your are deserializing into does not define that field. 
This may happen if you are deserializing it with a base-class type. 
Can you check if org.workplicity.marist.grounds.GroundRequest contains the fields that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Please try downloading the latest version of Gson, 1.7. It contains a lot of new features that may help you. See http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/6272c9be58676e47#.

For one, the Instance Creator thing is no longer necessary as Gson is able to automatically allocate heap space for any class instance without the use of a default constructor or instance creator.

As for the skipping of fields, by default, Gson will skip fields if they are "static", "transient" or "inner classes".

Answer (score 0):

> Debugging in NetBeans has revealed that the JsonObject 'jentry' has a hashtable with corresponding key value pairs for each data member in the JSON string; and the 'template' is stored as a hashtable within this hashtable which may or may not be a problem I honestly haven't been able to find out.

That's normal.  Gson initially reads JSON objects into a `JsonObject`, within which the JSON element names and values are stored in a `LinkedHashMap`.  So, if the JSON structure includes an object in an object, then the initial structure Gson reads the JSON into will be a `JsonObject` with a `LinkedHashMap`, within which one of the entries will have a value of another `JsonObject` with a `LinkedHashMap`.

The original post does not clearly describe that the contents of the maps in the `JsonObjects` were unexpectedly lacking.  It only described that some of the contents were noticed missing after serializing the deserialized data.  Since enough information to reproduce the problem was not provided, folks can only guess at what the problem might have been.  And inder's guess looks as good as any.  I see nothing that points to a deficiency in Gson.

Regarding the specific statement of the question title that "JSON deserialization using GSON skips data members from a hashmap within a hashmap", from the remaining contents of the question, I do not think the original question actually meant that the target Java structure was a map within a map.  If the target Java structure were a map within a map, then I've not been able to reproduce a scenario where Gson mysteriously skips some fields, provided that the JSON elements are properly bound to Java fields, and that handling for [Gson issue 325](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=325) is provided (with custom deserialization).